# EnvelopesApi.getDocument - error: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Tags: android, docusignapi

I'm testing Docusign embed signing with a Demo Account, with the Java SDK in an Android App. So far I was able to sign a PDF document and make the returnUrl send back to my app through deep linking. All good. But after receiving back the signing confirmation in the app, I need to get the Certificate of Completion. But when I call EnvelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "combined") I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

I know that accountId, envelopeId are valid, not null and correct. I'm also using the same ApiClient I used to sign the document, so it's also valid and working. Does anyone know What could be the problem in this call?

This is the call

```
EnvelopesApi api = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
try {

     // The error is in the line below:

     byte[] pdfBytes = api.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "combined");

} catch (ApiException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the complete error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATALEXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
               at com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType.getClass(GenericType.java:103)
               at com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType.<init>(GenericType.java:72)
               at com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi$24.<init>(EnvelopesApi.java:1928)
               at com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi.getDocument(EnvelopesApi.java:1928)
               at com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi.getDocument(EnvelopesApi.java:1849)
               at br.com.cbyk.privatelabel.NovaPropostaActivity$2.doInBackground(NovaPropostaActivity.java:454)
               at br.com.cbyk.privatelabel.NovaPropostaActivity$2.doInBackground(NovaPropostaActivity.java:448)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
File document = envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);
```

See the full api recipe [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/core_recipes/CoreRecipes.java#L552)

Comment: Maybe the api recipe is just wrong in this call, because "envelopesApi.getDocuments" does not return File type. It returns byte[]. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Any new thoughts on this, @CodingDawg?